# Replace Attributes Form and Automate Fields

Tags: fields-attributes, pyqgis-3, pyqt5, forms

I used **QT Creator** to create an .ui for my form.

I want to change the form attribute and automate some fields. Imagine I have an layer with field **name**, I want that field when the form appears, to already have **"ZAPM_NAME"** instead of default "NULL".

This need to be automatic with pyqgis and not in Proprieties > Attributes Form> And change the form manually.

I want this script to be ready when Qgis open. So when someone tries to create new feature, the form should appear.

Can someone explain me how can I achive that with pyqgis?